# Using parenthesis for "for"

Tags: scala

I wonder, why doesn't this code compile?

```
val files = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
for (file <- files if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")) {
  yield file
}
```

Comment: Do you mean why doesn't it compile, or "why, oh, why doesn't it compile" in the deep sense?

Comment: By parenthesis, do you mean braces?

Comment: Not an answer, but you'll probably want to write this as `(new java.io.File(".")).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".scala"))` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is, your code contains a syntax error in that the **yield** keyword is contained inside the code block being handed to the for-comprehension. When the compiler encounters the curly braces directly after your **for**, it treats that as a side effecting for-comprehension, and doesn't understand what you mean by **yield**.

For the long answer, we need to understand a little more about the for-comprehension.

For-comprehensions have many possible expressions, each seemingly minor difference drastically changing the behavior of the for-comprehension.

Let's take a look at the simplest syntax

```
for(generator1) { code_block }
```

Note that **generator1** and **code_block** are symbols, **not** literal code. A generator has the following syntax...

```
identifier <- expression
```

Note that just any expression won't work. For the example syntax above, **expression** must evaluate to some object that defines a **foreach** method, as this syntax for a for-comprehension denotes that **code_block** should be side-effecting code (i.e. mutates some variable in some outer scope, or writes to a database, or whatever...), and that the for-comprehension itself should not evaluate to a value (in fact, if you tried to assign the for expression to a variable, the value you would get would be Unit).

In your case, what you intended to write was the following, slightly more complicated syntax.

```
for(generator1 guard1) yield { code_block }
```

In this syntax, we've introduced a couple of new syntax elements, and, behind the scenes, some new requirements as well. First, let's break it down a bit.

As before, **guard1** is really a symbol, the actual syntax actually looks more like...

```
if boolean_expression
```

When you have a guard expression, this also means that the **expression** that we talked about earlier for **generator1** would have to also evaluate to an object that defined a **filter** method. Note specifically that we haven't talked about a specific trait/interface/abstract class. Scala's "for-comprehensions" utilize duck typing, so that any object that implements the methods required by the particular syntax you use are allowable inside of the for-comprehension construct. This is incredibly powerful.

Anyways, back to our new syntax, the other key difference is the **yields** keyword. This keyword imposes yet another limitation on our generator expression, in that now our generator must define a **map** method. However, this also lifts the restriction of having a **foreach** method, as you can't both have the **yield** keyword be present and absent in the same for-comprehension.

With the **yields** keyword there, the expectation is now that the **code_block** be non-side-effecting code, but rather some form of transformation. Also, the for-comprehension now evaluates to a value (similarly typed to the output type of the expression used for your generator). This is because, behind the scenes, the for-comprehension is really just calling **map**.

This should be enough information to answer your question, but I highly recommend reading up on map/flatmap/foreach and for-comprehensions, as there is a lot more I didn't cover here.

Answer (score 2):

How does this look to you?

```
if (flag) {
  // some code
} { else
  // other code
}
```

Does `else` looks to be in the right place? It's the same with with for-comprehensions: `yield` must come between the first parenthesis (or braces) and the expression that is being yielded.

Comment: Why doesn't that compile?

Comment: I know *that* it doesn't compile; I'm asking *why*.

Comment: @som-snytt `else` can only appear following an `if (expression) expression`, and here it appears as the first statement on a block.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't else just pop an operator stack, and if there's an if in there, we're good?  What's a couple of braces between friends? If some f-er downvotes my answer, I want to know *why*, besides the palaver of the green check answer which calls it "the yields keyword."  Is that too much to ask of SO?  Why didn't someone close this question? How can that answer get nine upvotes? Don't people read books anymore?  Ebooks at least?  But I appreciate your follow-up. You are the consummate educator.  I bet you already have the "consummate educator" badge.

Comment: Unfortunately, in most US states, if an educator tries to consummate, they're brought up on charges. (Full disclosure: I had to wait 15 seconds to finish this parody because of the SO re-comment limiter.)

Answer (score 1):

That must be why the bible saith:

```
Avoid the temptation to write things like this:

  for (file <- filesHere if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")) {
    yield file  // Syntax error!
  }
```

[chapter and verse](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html), just before [this anchor](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html#lst%3atransforming-an-array).

Hoping this helps: an expr after the `for` means foreach; a yield expr after the for means map.  There are certainly answers to that effect on SO.

Comment: The syntax is "for clauses yield body". That code doesn't match that syntax. Code that is syntactically incorrect doesn't compile. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: @ChristopherMartin There must be a deeper existential dilemma at stake here. Right?

Comment: @MariusKavansky For the record, I did.

Comment: Perhaps I could rephrase my explanation: "yield" is not a command by itself in Scala. It is only a part of the "for-yield" phrase. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas. The burden is on the asker to explain why that code *would* compile, else all we can do is argue against our own straw men.

Answer (score 1):

Put yield out fo braces

```
scala> val r = for (file <- files if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")) yield file

r: Array[java.io.File] = Array()
```

You can write braces after yield if you want: yield {file}